# iOS - Is application code(executable file) loaded in Heap memory?

Tags: ios, xcode, memory, frameworks, libraries

While studying dynamic and static library, I found an weird diagram in developer.apple.com.

[Overview of Dynamic Libraries from developer.apple.com](https://i.stack.imgur.com/47LjS.png)

This diagram is showing that when app launch starts, the application file is loaded in Heap area.

However, as far as I know, the executable file should be loaded in "code" area (out of other memory areas like stack, heap, code, data etc).

The apple docs doesn't mention in text that the application code is located in heap (only the diagram).

So I kind of thought that, the diagram represents the application code is rather a "code" area itself, not a part of heap.

I personally think that the application code is "code" area but I found a few articles telling that application code is loaded in heap referencing the above diagram.

Could anybody make me clear? Is application code really loaded in Heap in iOS?